# State of polymer <paper-icon-button>

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am trying to access the "pressed" property of a Polymer `<paper-icon-button>` through the DOM.

The use-case is the following : I am writing a Chrome extension to control Google Music through the Mediakeys. In the extension's "content script", I am doing `var btn_up = document.querySelector(".now-playing-actions paper-icon-button[data-rating][icon='sj:thumb-up-outline']")` to get access to the DOM element for the `thumb up` button. I'd like to get the state of the `pressed` property before using a `click` method on it if it is already set.

I always get either `undefined` or `false` and never `true`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you selector gets the right thing?  I've just tried in Chrome Dev Tools to locate a paper-icon-button on my page and checked the state of pressed, active and pointerDown - they are all false, but are all there, never undefined.

Comment: Yes I have used Chrome dev tools and now I always get "false". I was getting "undefined" but I found out why : Google Music changes the polymer elements from time to time and as such some become unavailable.